# MC Connect functionality with child business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, multi-org

If you are connecting an Org to the parent account in Marketing Cloud, what is the functionality within the child business units for the data coming in?

We would still like to be able to use the data coming in from the synchronized data extensions for our primary audience and also for journeys. Will operating out of a child business unit without multi-org setup be a hinderance or should we just implement multi-org if that is the case?

Comment: Do you mean that you want information from a single Salesforce organization to be available to the top-level account and Business Unit(s)? Do you have multiple Salesforce organizations which you will be connecting to a single Enterprise 2.0 account in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: Just one SF Org that will connect to a single 2.0 account, however, we operate out of a child business unit and want to know if there are any limitations to using the SF Data for our primary audience and journeys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice to make the synchronized data available to business units is to create query activities which target shared data extensions which can be accessed by the business units.

Multi-Org is meant for associating multiple Salesforce Organizations to a single Enterprise 2.0 account.